# How to replace a line in sed with unknown amount of whitespace?

Tags: regex, shell, sed

I would like to replace lines in a file with sed. But the line I am trying to replace contains an unknown amount of whitespace:

I've tried to match the whitespace characters with [[:space:]] or [[:blank:]] without luck:

I would like to replace

- `gender: FEMALE` with `gender: FEMALE_X`
- `gender:  FEMALE` with `gender: FEMALE_X`
- `gender:     FEMALE` with `gender: FEMALE_X`
- `gender:     FEMALE` with `gender: FEMALE_X`

How can I do this?

I've tried :

```
sed -i 's/gender:[[:space:]]FEMALE/gender: FEMALE_X/g'

sed -i 's/gender:[[:blank:]]FEMALE/gender: FEMALE_X/g'
```

But none of those work for all the cases above.

Answer (score 1):

You can repeat matched part as well with `&`:

```
sed -E 's/^gender: *FEMALE/&_X/' file
                   ^
              quantifier needed here
```

##### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `^` | the beginning of the string anchor |
| `gender:` | 'gender:' |
| `*` | a space (0 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `FEMALE` | 'FEMALE' |

Comment: How can I also make this work if there is an unknown amount of whitespace before gender?

Comment: `'s/^ *gender: *FEMALE/&_X/'`

Comment: How can I make this work if there is an unknown amount of whitespace after gender and before the ':'?

Comment: `'s/^ *gender *: *FEMALE/&_X/'` Thanks to accept/upvote answer if it was useful